# Reference of an Object in Java

Tags: java, object, reference

I am new to Java.
In this code snippet why -- if (t.canRecord == true) -- is true when, t an Object, just stores the reference and does not overrides the existing value.

```
class TapeDeck 
{
  boolean canRecord = false;

  void playTape() 
  {
    System.out.println("tape playing");
  }

  void recordTape() 
  {
    System.out.println("tape recording");
  }
}

class TapeDeckTestDrive 
{
  public static void main(String [] args) 
  {
    TapeDeck t=new TapeDeck();
    t.canRecord = true;
    t.playTape();
    if (t.canRecord == true) 
    {
      t.recordTape();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's true because you assign `true` to it in `t.canRecord = true;`

Comment: It's unclear which bit of this is confusing to you, to be honest. Could you give more details? What would you expect to happen, and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In the static main method, you create a new instance of `TapeDeck`. For this instance the value of `canRecord`is set to `false`.
- As `canRecord` is not set to private visibility , you are here allowed to access it directly via `t.canRecord`.  By `t.canRecord = true` you are not *overriding* but *overwriting* the existing value of `false`with `true`.
- The if-condition evaluates to `true`as (i) `t.canRecord` is `true` and (ii) the comparison with `true`results in `true`.